# Query performance on different servers

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan

Same query with select and where clause is less than 2 seconds on one server and same query takes more than 10 minutes on another server.
Both servers have same max dop and parallelism settings. Both servers have same indexes and both were updated and rebuild regualry. even the database compatability, sql server version and config details are same on both servers also same number of cpu cores and windows versions everything, please advise what else i am missing to check?
important note is slower server had high cpu issues same time when the query ran. execution plan was also compared . the difference is on faster server i see parallelism but on slower server i dont see parallelism being used in the plan.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: thank you. my environment is ms sql server

Answer (score 1):

You should look into why the query plans are different. I find it easiest to just look at the estimates from the query plans.

My guess would be a case of parameter sniffing, since you mentioned that configurations are the same (but do double check parallelism settings)

To diagnose, right click each query plan, show xml, find compiled parameters (near the bottom) and check if they're the same. If not, odds are that one parameter causes a parallelized plan, the other a single threaded plan.

Whichever parameter is used first after a plan cache reset (DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, sliding expiration or server restart) gets to decide which plan is used for each subsequent execution.

If the compiled parameters are the same, but estimates are not (look at expected rows to be returned from each operation), then statistics is a very good bet, see Joe Hayes answer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is the blocking. While executing the query on the 'slow' server run below query to see what is actually running on the server and check for blocked sessions.

```
SELECT 
        command, DB_NAME(database_id) as DbName, percent_complete as PctComp,  reads,writes, logical_reads,
        Cpu_time/1000 as CpuSec, total_elapsed_Time/1000 as ElapsSec, 
        SUBSTRING ( s.text, statement_start_offset/2+1, 4096 ) as StatementTxt, 
        start_time, session_id, blocking_session_id, open_transaction_count 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s 
order by start_time
```

The second thing you can try is to clear query plan for only this query because yo said the plan was different on both servers. Here is the article on how to do it:
https://sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-removing-a-specific-plan-from-the-plan-cache-using-dbcc-freeproccache/

But blocking is more probable.

If you would like to **down vote** this answer, please take your time to leave a comment of what you think is wrong here. I would like to know and be better next time.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise and inputs. It helped in getting the root cause of the issue  especially with costly queries,

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your statistics are up-to-date on the slower server?
There's a nice, complete, straight-forward reference here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-statistics-and-how-to-perform-update-statistics-in-sql/

SQL Server statistics can get out-of-whack in a couple ways that I'm aware of:

1. Something can be amiss in your auto-update settings
2. On older version of SQL Server in particular, very large tables can have sufficient changes to make statistics non-efficient without triggering an auto-update.

I know this isn't a common thing to have to do in MSSQL, but I would start by updating statistics on the tables involved in the query just to eliminate that as a culprit.

Good luck!